# Golang db2cli running select query gets cgo error

Tags: go, db2

I'm trying to use db2cli library (https://bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli/) to implement DB2 queries (select, insert, delete). But get CGO error when trying to run select queries. Here is my code:

```
db, err := sql.Open("db2-cli", *connStr)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer db.Close()
rows, err := db.Query("select * from tab")
```

The error is:

```
panic: runtime error: cgo argument has Go pointer to Go pointer

goroutine 1 [running]:
bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli/api.SQLBindCol.func1(0x9000100010001, 0xc420062238, 0xa00000006, 0xc420062218, 0x5b00000040)
```

......

If I manually run the select queries from DB2 command line, it will return correct results. And other type of queries (insert, delete etc.) with Go language code also work correctly. I tried to set GODEBUG=cgocheck=0, but still get the same issue. Has anyone encountered similar problems when using db2cli?

Comment: Edit your question to show the code for how you retrieve the result-set columns .   Does the sample program shown on https://bitbucket.org/phiggins/db2cli/  work correctly on your environment?  Also specify you operating-system.  Both the sample program and general SELECT works correctly for me. So most likely you have a programming error, but unless you show your code I can't help you further.

Comment: @mao thanks for your help! I just figured out it was a problem about retrieving result set. The error stack trace pointed to the line db.Query() so I didn't realize it's because I was using incorrect way to retrieve results. Now it working correctly. Thanks!